Is there a non-constant, absolutely monotonic function on $[0, \infty)$ which is constant on an interval?
A function $f$ is called absolutely monotonic on an interval if $f$ is smooth and it's $n$th derivative is non-negative on that interval for all $n \geq 1$. Is there an absolutely monotonic function which is non-constant but is constant on an interval?
I know there are many ways to construct smooth functions that are constant on only part of their domain, but do any of them yield an absolutely monotonic function? I am particularly interested in a function on $[0, \infty)$ which is constant on an interval $[0,a]$, but will accept any intervals (as long as the function itself is non-constant), or a proof that no such function exists.
As pointed out in the comments, this is equivalent to finding a non-constant, absolutely monotonic function whose $n$th derivatives all vanish at a single point. $e^{-\frac{1}{x-1}}$ has vanishing derivatives at 1 but is not absolutely monotonic; $e^x$ is absolutely monotonic but does not have vanishing derivatives at any point.

$f(x)=0$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/(x-1)}$ for $x>1.$

Please do not rely on the tile of your MSE questions for important information. The body should be self-contained. As for the maths, a constant function is absolutely monotonic and so if you intermingle constant functions with absolutely monotonic functions all of whose derivatives are zero at an end of an interval, you wll get what you want.I see that while I have been typing this, @RyszardSzwarc has given you a nice explicit example.

@RyszardSzwarc doesn't that have negative second derivative?

@RobArthan I've edited the question to make it more self-contained. What I don't understand is how to construct a non-constant, absolutely monotonic function with all its derivatives vanishing at a given point - unless I'm mistaken,  RyszardSzwarc's example is monotonic but not absolutely monotonic.

My bad. I have missed the assumption "absolutely". In my example the function cannot be absolutely monotonic as the limit of $f'$ at $\infty$ is constant (equal $0$).

I'm trying to remember if $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}$ works for this.   Has to...  It's a classic example of a function whose Taylor series at $0$ is the zero function, so has a "radius of agreement" of zero.

@EricTowers WolframAlpha says the second derivative of $e^{-1/{x^2}}$ is $\frac{e^{-1/{x^2}}(4 - 6x^2)}{x^6}$, which takes negative values (for example, at $x = 1$). The "absolutely monotonic" condition is quite strong - for example, I'm not sure if things like weighted sums with a smooth sigmoid preserve it.

@MartianInvader : The exponential crushes the rational expression to $0$ at $x = 0$.

More precisely, the function is $$ \begin{cases}0,& x = 0 \ \mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2},& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\text{.}  $$  Its Maclaurin series is $0$.  Shift the right half of it and paste constant $0$ out to its new starting point.

@EricTowers My previous comment was pointing out that it is not absolutely monotonic on $[0, \infty)$. Are you claiming it is absolutely monotonic on a smaller interval? Playing around in Wolfram Alpha seems to show its successively higher derivatives take negative values closer and closer to $x=0$...

any absolutely monotonic function is analytic so the answer to your question is negative (the proof is very easy using the integral form of the Taylor remainder and easy majorizations)

Maybe a smooth transition function could do the trick? something like a displaced version of this example

We will show that $f'$ cannot vanish on $(0,\infty).$ Let $f'(a)=0$ for some $a>0.$    As $f'$ is increasing and nonnegative we get $f'(x)= 0$ for $(0,a].$
According to the Bernstein theorem a function $g(x)$ on $(-\infty,0]$ is absolutely monotonic iff
$$ g(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{tx}\,d\mu(t)\quad (*)$$ where $\mu$ is a finite measure on $[0,\infty).$
For $b>0$  consider the function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x< -a-b\\
f'(x+a+b) & -a-b\le x\le 0\end{cases} $$ Then $g$ is nonnegative, absolutely monotonic on $(-\infty,0]$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\le -b.$
By $(*)$ we get
$$0=g(-b)=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-bt}d\mu(t)$$ which implies $\mu=0.$ Again by $(*)$ we get $g(x)=0.$  Therefore $f'(x)$ vanishes on $[0,a+b].$ As $b$ is arbitrary the function $f'$ vanishes on $[0,\infty),$ i.e. $f$ is constant.

Of course $f$ must be constant. From (* ) of ryszard szwarc answer, $f$ can be extended to an analytic function on the strip $\Re z<0$ and from the isolated zeros principle $f$ is constant in the strip, being constant on a real interval.

I do not quite get your reasoning as $f$ does not satisfy $(*).$ The function $f$ is absolutely monotonic on the positive half line.

You are right, I read the question too quickly. By the way, I went to Feller's book 'An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications' Vol 2 page 222 Theorem 3 saying that $f$ is absolutely monotonic on $(0,1)$ if and only if $f(x)=\sum_na_nx^n$ with $a_n\geq 0$ which clearly answers to the initial question.

Thus the function is entire as the conclusion holds for every interval $(0,a).$
